# Angularjs Populating Form data (Select from other Select)

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, select

I am building a little shopping cart. I have different products that each have different options. The options select should only show the options for the selected product.

1. How do i populate the selects? Is my $scope.products even possible this way?
2. Once i populate the options, each option should change the cost/price of the selected product. How do i achieve this kind of "chain-binding" with Angular?

My JS looks like that:

```
$scope.products = [{
    name: 'Normal Product',
    cost: 25,
    options: ["Option #1", "Option #2"]
},

{
    name: 'Cool Product',
    cost: 100,
    options: ["Option #1", "Option #2"]
}, {
    name: 'Sick Produckt',
    cost: 150,
    options: ["Option #1", "Option #2"]
}];
```

And HTML:

```
<td>
<select ng-model="item.product" ng-options="p.name for p in products">
</select>
</td>
<td <select ng-model="item.option" ng-options="o for o in item.product.options">
</select>
</td>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NyvbN/2/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in the code.

Comment: On checking your fiddle with the typo fixed I found that the product options are still not listing. Can you please check it.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem was that you did not close the td tag: You have `<td` without closing >

```
  <td> <select ng-model="item.option" ng-options="o for o in item.product.options">
```

Your fiddle works fine otherwise.